# Find other element with same directive within same scope?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is there any way to find other element with same directive applied within same scope?

I want to use this info to create `matching input values` directive.

e.g. I might have a template with a few inputs which all using same directive:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <input type="text" same-value>
    <input type="text" same-value>
</div>
```

Primarily I would use this for comparing password & password repeat, but I wanted to make this more general directive.

Comment: You should probably use a parent directive with a controller.
Please give more specific information about what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a parent directive and communicate between children and parent via the controller or you can create a service that is shared across instances.

Another option is to provide shared data and functionality when the directive is declared, as in:

```
angular.module("whatever").directive("sameValue", function() {

    var sameValueInstances = [];    

    return {
        link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
            sameValueInstances.push(scope);

            // register listener to remove from array when destroyed..


            // do something with the instance array
            sameValueInstances.forEach(...);
        }
    };

});
```

There is more than one instance of the directive, but there is only one instance of the declaration of the directive (the function itself). The declaration is shared and therefore `sameValueInstances` are shared. When angular instantiates a directive, it will create a new scope and cal the link function. Each instance gets its own scope, which is why we put the scopes on the instances. We then use whatever data we add to the scope to identify instances and can use functions on scope to communicate.

Comment: The above will work cause there will be a single instance of directive? What about isolated scopes?

Comment: @Iladarsda, It will work, the precise mechanism can be hard to understand. I added an explanation.

Comment: This does make sense. Last unlikely scenario, how does it limit itself to a single `$controller scope`. e.g. when you have multiple controller on a page?

Comment: @Iladarsda, sorry, I don't understand the second question.

Comment: In case we use the this directive on multiple views, we could have a case when we display two controllers/views at the same time (e.g. using ui-router). In this case our `directive.sameValueInstances` will collect all instances on the directive from all controllers/views. This is very edge scenario just wanted to know your thoughts on this.

Comment: @Iladarsda, if you have multiple instances that need to be in separate groups, then I would strongly recommend using a container directive with a defined controller and then have the instances be child directives of the container and communicate through the controller. That's also more standard angular.

Comment: it worked, we can maintain scope of all the variable from directive itself